# rails wont load stylesheet or javascript files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

im trying to load onepage-scroll https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) to my rails app but it wont load it just show plain text. im new to rails as well im still learning.

here is the code for the page im trying to get to work. pages#**index.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Demo</title>
  <meta name="author" content="#" />
  <meta name="description" content="#" />
  <meta name="keywords"  content="#" />
  <meta name="Resource-type" content="Document" />



  <% stylesheet_link_tag 'onepage-scroll' %>

  <% javascript_include_tag 'jquery.onepage-scroll.js' %>


</head>

<body>

<div class="main">
  <section>
    <h3>hello</h3>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>hello</h3>
  </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

if any one can help me i will greatly appreciate. thanks

Comment: Did you try adding them to application.js and application.css?

Comment: @Thresh no i didn't how do you do it?

Comment: where do you put your js file?

Comment: @GingerJim i put js files in app/assets/javascript and for css i put in app/assets/stylesheets

Comment: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'onepage-scroll' %>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.onepage-scroll.js' %>

Answer (score 0):

Just add `=`

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'onepage-scroll' %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.onepage-scroll.js' %>
```